# SQL query for SQLZOO exercise 15 of More JOIN operations

Tags: sql, join

I don't know why the following SQL code is not working. If I allow a.name to be 'Art Garfunkel', the only output I get is that name two times. If not then get an empty output.

```
SELECT a.name
  FROM actor a
 INNER 
  JOIN casting c 
    ON a.id = c.actorid
 INNER 
  JOIN movie m ON c.movieid = m.id
 WHERE m.id IN (
          SELECT c.movieid
            FROM casting
           WHERE c.actorid IN (
                    SELECT a.id
                     FROM actor
                    WHERE a.name = 'Art Garfunkel'
                  )
        )
    AND a.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'

[![enter image description here][1]][1];
```

[image: The three tables given by the exercise]

Comment: You post a broken query without telling us what the query supposed to do.  How do you think we can help you???

Answer (score 0):

Tip - formatting your queries well makes debugging a lot easier. Your future self and coworkers will be happier for it.

Doesn't have to look like this, but just some type of consistent indentation.

In your case, you were 99% there. But those inner subqueries were missing their aliases, so it was doing some very strange correlated subquery.

I didn't do it here, but it's also good to not have aliases reused in subqueries. When queries get long it's hard to keep track of the scope.

```
SELECT a.name
  FROM actor a
 INNER 
  JOIN casting c 
    ON a.id = c.actorid
 INNER 
  JOIN movie m 
    ON c.movieid = m.id
 WHERE m.id IN (
          SELECT c.movieid
            FROM casting c
           WHERE c.actorid IN (
                    SELECT a.id
                      FROM actor a
                     WHERE a.name = 'Art Garfunkel'
                  )
        )
    AND a.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected Query**

```
SELECT a.name FROM actor a INNER JOIN casting c ON a.id = c.actorid INNER JOIN movie m ON c.movieid = m.id
WHERE m.id IN (
SELECT c.movieid FROM casting as c
WHERE c.actorid IN (
SELECT a.id FROM actor as a
WHERE a.name = 'Art Garfunkel'))
AND a.name <> 'Art Garfunkel';
```

There is an mistake in use of aliases for the tables **(a for actor, c for casting, m for movie)** in the correct query.

To know more : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp